# Useful techniques for disproving a limit using epsilon and delta definition

Tags: calculus, limits, definition

I am aware that this question has been asked before, but it seems that the answers give rise to more questions

Here is what I know, the formal definition of a limit states that:

if $L$ **is** the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$ the exist a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-c| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0\, (|x-c| < \delta \rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \epsilon)$

now to disprove a limit the logical thing to do is to prove the negation of that statement:

if $L$ **is not** the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$, then there exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, $|x-c| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - L| \geqslant\epsilon$

$\exists\epsilon>0, \forall\delta>0\, (|x-c| < \delta \land |f(x) - L| \geqslant \epsilon)$

but in some questions asked before the answers usually wrote the negation like this:

if $L$ **is not** the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$, then there exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, $|x-c| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - L| \geqslant\epsilon$, **for some $x$**

this is a huge difference since a quantifier for x is not defined in any of the original written definitions I could find in a book, but $\forall x$ is written in *some* of them. Is the quantifier for x implied in the definition?

secondly, if we need to find $\epsilon$ to disprove the proposition, are there any techniques to find it?

say we need to disprove $\lim_{x \to 2} 5x-2 = 9$, what is the suitable $\epsilon$ value we can use?

Comment: The quantifier of $x$ in the definition of limit should be $\forall x\in D$, where $D$ is the domain of the function. The negation should be as in the second version that you quoted, with $\exists x\in D$. Part of the definition of limit is that $D$ has $c$ as accumulation point. So, strictly speaking the negation also has an "OR $c$ is not an accumulation point of $D$". But well, this is a way of failing to have limit that is less interesting.

Comment: You have to [include the quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) for x: $∀ϵ>0,∃δ>0, \forall x(|x−c|<δ→|f(x)−L|<ϵ)$

Comment: Regarding techniques, there are no general ones. In your example the limit exists and is $5\cdot 2-2=7$. Any $0<\epsilon< |7-9|=2$ should work. If the limit doesn't exist, but for some sequence $x_n\to c$ you have $\lim_n f(x_n)=L$, and you are disproving $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=M$, with $M\neq L$, then any $0<\epsilon<|L-M|$ should work. This includes the cases $L=\pm\infty$, in which case any $\epsilon>0$ would work.

Comment: By the way, your definitions of a limit are missing a piece.  It should be $\color{red}{0 < } ~ |x - c| < \delta.$